# Probability of getting at least 1 white ball

Tags: probability

There's 1 box with 10 balls:

3 white
2 black
5 blue

2 balls are removed the box randomly, and the first one is not replaced.

What is the probability of getting at least 1 white ball?

Here's what I cooked up:

The probability of getting at least 1 white ball equals the sum of the probabilities of getting a white ball first and getting a white ball second. The probability of getting a white ball on the first one is 3/10. The probability of getting a white ball on the second one is 2/9.

So the probability would be:

3/10 + 2/9 = 47/90

I'm solving this on a book which says the answer is 8/15.

So, my answer is 0.52222..., and their answer is 0.5333...

Am I doing anything wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What if the first ball is not white?

Comment: Then it'd be 3/10 + 3/9, and that is also not 8/15...

Comment: The probability of the second ball being white is _not independent_ of whether or not the first ball is white. Thus, your summation clause does not apply. (And even if it did, you would still have to correct for the case that _both_ occurred, which you then counted twice.)

Comment: If you apply your argument to the case of drawing three balls, each of which is blue, you'd get $95/72$..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here Question is What is the probability of getting ***at least 1 white ball*** ?
So there are 3 possible cases as follows

1. 1st is white **AND** 2nd is not for that  (3/10) * (7/9)

**OR** 2. 1st is not white **AND** 2nd is white for that (7/10)*(3/9) (*adding dummy characters in order to save the edit*)

**OR** 3. both are white for that (3/10) * (2/9)

for answer add these 3 cases so answer is 48/90 which is 0.533333
 In probability questions remember  **OR** means **ADD**, **AND** means **Multiply**

Comment: What's that thing about punctuation again? Ah, I recall. It makes a piece of text _readable_...

Comment: now answer is clear to you?

Comment: Yes, but it still misses punctuation. Take your time to properly write your answer; it is more satisfactory and useful if you do.

Comment: this is my 1st day on this website. i will improve

Comment: Which is precisely why I have given you the advice :). Have a good time. PS: The advice also applies to comments; I'm sure you'll get it soon enough.

Answer (score 1):

You want to know the probability of "one of the two balls is white" = "the first ball is white OR (the first ball isn't white AND the second ball is white)".

OR is +

AND is $\times$

So you get $\frac{3}{10} + \frac{10-3}{10}\times \frac{3}{10-1}$.

$\frac{3}{10}$ and $\frac{10-3}{10}$ because you have 3 white balls and 10 balls so 10 - 3 not-white balls

$\frac{3}{10-1}$ because when you pick the second ball, you removed one non-white ball

Answer (score 0):

or you can arrive at the same answer by thinking in reverse.  If at least one ball is white, then the only other combination is Non-white in the 1st pick and No-white in the 2nd pick.  Then 1-(2 non-white probability)=at least 1 white picked!

So 1st pick for non-white = 7/10  and the 2nd pick for non-white = 6/9.  This probability for this combination is 7/10 x 6/9 = 7/15.  So the probability of getting at least 1 white = 1-7/15= 8/15 = 0.53333....